# How can i use $mq props in my components in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use vue-mq package for my responsive media query. I am facing problem when trying to make a grid system using the `$mq` prop.

My code looks something like this:

```html
<v-col 
 v-for="(exploreProduct,index) in exploreNeedsProducts" 
 :key="index" 
 :cols="$mq | mq({ mobile: 2, tablet: 4, laptop: 6 })">
```

I am sure my process is somewhat wrong because `v-col` don't have `:column` props. I tried using `:cols` but still doesn't works. According to the documentation:

```html
<grid-component :column="$mq | mq({
      phone: 2,
      tablet: 3,
      laptop: 4
  })">
</grid-component>
```

Plugin registration:

```js
Vue.use(VueMq, {
  breakpoints: {
    mobile: 450,
    tablet: 900,
    laptop: 1250,
    desktop: Infinity,
  }
});
```

The question is how do I implement this code in my `v-col`?

Comment: Are you also using Vuetify with this?

Comment: Yes I am using vuetify too @YomS.

Comment: OK, then why bother reinventing the wheel when [Vuetify already has one](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids#grid-system)?

Comment: Just trying to explore the package